# intersystems cache instring between 2 special characters

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I need to get the value in the middle of a string.
The string is a name in the format of `Lastname, Firstname Middlename`

I have isolated the last name with the following:
`SUBSTRING(p.Name,1, INSTR(p.Name,',',1)-1) as "Surname"`

I now need to isolate the firstname only. I am trying to use the same kind of logic with `substring` and `instr` but I'm having trouble doing it. Here's what I've come up with so far:
`SUBSTRING(p.Name, INSTR(p.Name,',',1)+1, INSTR(p.Name,' ')) as "Patient"`

This produces `Firstname Middlename`

Anyone know how I can parse the characters between the comma and the space? Note this is in InterSystems Cache

[Instr notes](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_instr)
[Substring notes](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20161/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_substring)

Answer (score 4):

Use [$Piece](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_d_piece) function to return a substring identified by a delimiter:

`SELECT $PIECE($PIECE('Lastname, Firstname Middlename', ',', 2), ' ', 2)`

Yields Firstname.